# How to preserve the type of the members of a jsonb array?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have this simple query :

```
select jsonb_path_query_first(a,'$[0]')
from (values (jsonb_build_array(1, 2, 3))) as "t" ("a")
```

Its working fine, but i get jsob type, when i would like to get integer type.
Somehow the jsob array lost the types of the members.

Is there a way to make jsob to know the types, so when i access them i get the types also? Because manual casting all the time makes things more complicated than they should be.

For example this won't compile without manual casting:

````
select jsonb_path_query_first(a,'$[0]')+1
from (values (jsonb_build_array(1, 2, 3))) as "t" ("a")```
````

Comment: A jsonb array contains other jsonb elements - numbers, strings, booleans, nulls, arrays or objects. It does not contain postgres integers. The concrete jsonb value you're building contains numbers, yes, but the query (whose return type must be fixed before executing) does not know that, and no, it cannot know that.

Comment: thank you for helping me, i updated the question, all i want is make the addition(+) to work without manual casting, because its tedious and verbose to add casting, each time you access a jsonb_array. I don't want to use sql arrays, i want to use jsonb_arrays.

Comment: Maybe you just shouldn't use jsonb? Why don't you want to use sql arrays? What actual problem are you trying to solve with your query?

Comment: Because i am planning to use json anyways, and i don't want to have multiple array types, its confusing not knowing what kind of array it is, each have different operators making things complicated. In mongodb we have arrays inside json and there isn't problem like this, so i was hoping there is a way in postgres also.

Comment: Well if you want to do operations on json values only, you can use `jsonb_path_query_first(a,'$[0] + 1')`

Comment: "*its confusing not knowing what kind of array it is*" - well that's always the case when using `jsonb` - in fact you don't even know whether it's an array, it might be anything else. If you want to know what types you are dealing with, and want your queries to know too, then you'll need to declare the array types in your schema.

Comment: if i understand correctly all jsonb values are just jsonb without types? So each time i access them i need, i need manual casting? the one that you sended works, maybe will help me with other problems also, i am new to postgres and jsob, i am learning those, hoping to use them as i used json in mongodb, or even better if possible. In any case thank you for helping me.

Comment: Yes, there is just one type `jsonb` for all these values, whether that's `'1'`, `'"string"'`, `'true'`, `'{"some": "object"}'`, `'null'`, or `'[1, false, "string", {}]'`. Such heterogeneous structures are exactly where you'd use json - you declare the column type as `jsonb` and then you can store any of these values in different rows. But if you know the properties beforehand, and they should be the same for all rows, you should better use individual columns (or a composite type) with a specific type.